# PGFplotstable: Is it possible to set a number format for a *row* instead of a column?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

Using pgfplotstable, it's straightforward to set a column number format using

```
columns/(columnname)/.style={(format)}
```

What I would like to do is change the number format of a particular row. In my case, the last row of my table is in percent format, whereas the rest of the table is fixed point format.

Is there a way to set the number format of a row, that overrides the number format of all the columns?

As a follow-up question, is there a number format preset for percentages?

Cheers

**EDIT:** 
I've now got it closer to working, thanks to Christian. However, I'm now having an issue where two "%" signs appear in each of the columns that `dec sep align` creates. How can I remove the first one? See the last row of the image to understand what I mean.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "number format preset for percentages"? Do you mean something which appends "%"? I believe there is some example in the manual. Or do you want to multiply numbers by 100 and append "%"? This should not be too difficult using some numeric postprocessor, but there is no style preset.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Yes, I was thinking of the latter: multiply by 100 and append "%". However, the former would be acceptable as well. Unfortunately I can't find the example in the manual... I did a search for "\%" since a search for % brings up too many results.. also searched for "percent". Do you happen to know what section of the manual it is in?

Comment: See my edited answer. Note that the manual contains an example with \EUR, not with \% (sorry).

Comment: I posted a separate question and wrote my answer to that thread to simplify searches for that topic. Please see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65760/pgfplotstable-how-can-i-add-percent-signs-and-respect-dec-sep-align/65761#65761 fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pgfplotstable has styles like `every row no <index>` and some other styles as well.

However, these styles are applied quite late in the processing: the content is already fixed at that stage.

I accept this as a feature request.

However, there is a simple way to enable such a style: the styles named `every row <rowindex> column <colindex>`. These styles *allow* changes to the content generation, in particular, they respect changes to the number format.

You can group a sequence of such styles to change all values of a specific column easily using

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    % #1 = row index
    % #2 = row style keys
    row style/.style 2 args={
        every row #1 column 0/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 1/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 2/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 3/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 4/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 5/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 6/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 7/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 8/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 9/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 10/.style={#2},
    }
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row style={3}{sci},
]{
    a b
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
    6 6
    7 7
    8 8
    9 9
    10 10
}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT: concerning your second question: you wanted to format percentages (i.e. to multiply with 100 and to append '%'):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/A/.style={
        column type=r,
        preproc/expr={100*##1},
        postproc cell content/.append style={
            /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{\%},
        },
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
    },
]
{
 A
 0.01
 1
 0.1234
 0.5
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Thanks! Now if I could only find the way to append "%" like you mentioned I'd be all set...

Comment: Hmm... actually, your edit assigns the % symbol to a whole column, but I actually need it for a row... Is there a way to incorporate the `/.add={}{\%}` into the `row style` arguments? Maybe I'm being dense, but I can't see how that's done...

Comment: Ok, I figured out a way to incorporate the `/.add={}{\%}` into the `row style` arguments. However, since I'm using `dec sep align` on the rows, pgfplots creates additional rows. The problem is that the new code is adding "%" signs in both of the columns. See picture I attached in the OP. I tried removing the code for every other column number, but I guess since that happens before the `dec sep align` the columns haven't been split yet so it just removes the "%" for the entire column

Answer (score 1):

For those who'd like to know my solution for applying the percentages format to a row instead of a column, just input the code from Christian's answer in [Pgfplotstable: how can I add percent signs (and respect dec sep align)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65760/pgfplotstable-how-can-i-add-percent-signs-and-respect-dec-sep-align/65761#65761) as the second argument `{#2}`:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    % #1 = row index
    % #2 = row style keys
    row style/.style 2 args={
        every row #1 column 0/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 1/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 2/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 3/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 4/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 5/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 6/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 7/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 8/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 9/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 10/.style={#2},
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row style={(the row number with percentage data)}{precision=2,postproc cell content/.append code={
                \ifnum1=\pgfplotstablepartno
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={}{\%}}%
                \fi
    }}
    ]{\datatable}
```