# Pgfplotstable: how can I add percent signs (and respect dec sep align)?

Tags: pgfplotstable

My data contains a column with numbers like `0.01` or `0.9412` which I want to display as `1.00%` and `94.12%` . I would like to declare the column by means of `dec sep align`. How can I do that?

[This question arose after the answer for [PGFplotstable: Is it possible to set a number format for a *row* instead of a column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/pgfplotstable-is-it-possible-to-set-a-number-format-for-a-row-instead-of-a-co) has been accepted. I add it as separate answer to simplify searching]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key idea is to use

1. a preprocessing style which multiplies the values by 100
2. a postprocessing style which appends the percent sign

However, the postprocessing style is applied to *two* cells because `dec sep align` creates two artifical cells. The manual states that `\pgfplotstablepartno` can be used to identify which part is currently being postprocessed. A complete solution could be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/A/.style={
        column type=r,
        dec sep align,
        preproc/expr={100*##1},
        postproc cell content/.append code={
            \ifnum1=\pgfplotstablepartno
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={}{\%}}%
            \fi
        },
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
    },
]
{
 A
 0.01
 1
 0.1234
 0.5
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is some deep magic. Thank you, it worked flawlessly!

Comment: I posted a follow-up answer explaining how to make this work for rows instead of columns at the original question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/pgfplotstable-is-it-possible-to-set-a-number-format-for-a-row-instead-of-a-co/65774#65774