# Precision for one row only

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have an array with three rows and I would like that the last row has a specific format.

There is a command `every row no/.style`, but it wouldn't work in our context because the processing is applied quite late, see [PGFplotstable: Is it possible to set a number format for a *row* instead of a column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/pgfplotstable-is-it-possible-to-set-a-number-format-for-a-row-instead-of-a-co).

Here is the code from Jake with the result.

My question is now : how can I define, say `precision=0` for the third row ?

[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{
    row style/.style 2 args={
        postproc cell content/.append code={%
            \count0=\pgfplotstablerow
            \advance\count0 by1\relax
            \ifnum\count0=#1
                \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
            \fi
        }
    }
}


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    row style={3}{@cell content=\bfseries #1\,\%},
    col sep=&,row sep=\\
]{
colA & colB & colC \\
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23.4 \\
33.3 & 43.3 & 12 \\
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i don't think your reasoning applies to that style I'll have a look lqter but it shiuld work because post processing happens almost at the identical location for that style too

Comment: I really appreciate your current solution, which works well for more general codes.

Comment: oh don't get me wrong I'm just curious about the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is actually a style for a row index used as `every row <index>/.style` but I don't see why it's not invoked. So I made an iterative code until I can understand what the problem is because `every row no <index> column no <index>` works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{my style/.style={
        every row no 2 column no #1/.style={%
            postproc cell content/.style={
                @cell content={$\mathbf{%
                               \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]{####1}}$\,\textbf{\%}%
                }%
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    my style/.list={0,...,2},
    col sep=&,row sep=\\,
]{
colA & colB & colC \\
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23.4 \\
33.3 & 43.3 & 12 \\
}

\end{document}
```

[image]